# Oracle Procedure to return average in a list of student grades

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

SUBJECT

```
STDID   SUBJID   SEMESTER_YEAR  GRADE    FREQ   STATUS
1111    2         2/2018          6       75    ok
1111    13        2/2018          7       100   ok
1111    4         1/2018          5       90    ok
1111    7         1/2018          10      95    ok
1111    9         2/2018          8       75    ok
1122    2         2/2017          3       75    no
1122    13        2/2017          5       100   ok
1122    4         1/2017          5       90    ok
1122    7         1/2017          10      95    ok
1122    9         2/2017          8       75    ok
1113    2         2/2018          6       75    ok
1113    13        2/2018          7       100   ok
1113    4         1/2018          5       90    ok
1113    7         1/2018          4       95    no
1113    9         2/2018          8       75    ok
1132    2         2/2018          3       75    no
1132    13        2/2018          7       100   ok
1132    4         1/2018          5       90    ok
1132    7         1/2018          4       95    no
1132    9         2/2018          8       75    ok
```

And the other: STUDENT

```
            STDID     NAME      DATA_NASC
            1111    gabriel     12-APR-70
            1112    pedro       12-JUN-70
            1113    lucas       12-MAR-70
            1114    mariana     12-FEB-70
            1115    klemer      12-SEP-70
            1116    jose        12-DEC-70
            1117    vitor       12-NOV-70
            1118    artur       12-APR-70
            1119    bia         12-NOV-70
            1120    julia       12-MAR-70
            1121    rafaela     12-JAN-70
            1122    augusto     12-FEB-70
            1123    eneas       12-JUL-70
            1124    zezinho     12-APR-70
            1125    hugo        12-APR-70
            1126    matheus     12-APR-70
            1127    diana       12-APR-70
            1128    andre       12-APR-70
            1129    reco        12-APR-70
```

I'm trying to create a procedure that, given a semester/year, for each subject (SUBJID) within that semester, output the student ID, student name and their respective grades, frequencies and status on those subjects. For each subject listed, I need to show also the general average of students grades on that subject

Already done this, but I'm stuck, hope someone can help me with the procedure and selection:

```
SELECT STUDENT.NAME
     , SUBJECT.STDID
     , SUBJECT.SUBJID
     , SUBJECT.SEMESTER_YEAR
     , AVG(SUBJECT.GRADE) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY SUBJECT.SUBJID) AS AVERAGE_GRADE_BY_SUBJ
FROM SUBJECT, STUDENT
     WHERE SUBJECT.SEMESTER_YEAR = '1/2018'
     AND SUBJECT.STDID = STUDENT.STDID
ORDER BY SUBJECT.SUBJID;
```

EXAMPLE OF OUTPUT I NEED:

```
NAME             STDID        SUBJID    SEMESTER_YEAR   AVERAGE_GRADE_BY_SUBJ
gabriel          1111           4         1/2018               5
lucas            1113           4         1/2018               5
marcello         1132           4         1/2018               5
lucas            1113           7         1/2018               6,5
marcello         1132           7         1/2018               6,5
gabriel          1111           7         1/2018               6,5
```

Comment: Thanks Artur Ferreira.  I hoped you might be able to clarify what is meant by "output" here.  Do you just need to print the query result for the input semester-year, or do you need to return a structured data-set that can be re-used by other functions/procedures?

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of the output you want to see please?

Comment: Sure!Output some query like this:

``` 
NAME STDID SUBJID     SEMESTER_YEAR AVG_BY_GRADE
gabriel  1111 4               1/2018                           5
lucas  1113 4               1/2018                           5
marcello  1132 4               1/2018                           5
lucas  1113 7               1/2018                           6
marcello  1132 7               1/2018                           6
gabriel  1111 7               1/2018                           6```

Comment: How do you expect the procedure to output the values? Using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` or are you expecting it to return a cursor or using collections of objects or something else?

Comment: How to get `6,5` would be possible `10+4+4=18` and `18/3=6` for `subjid = 7` and you should already get it. And I cannot see `marcello` in the `student` table .Btw do not use former-style SQL Select statement with comma-seperated join, use explicit one instead.

Comment: @ArturFerreira By the way, your caps lock is on ;)